# Apply for a US visit visa in Germany without being a resident

Tags: usa, visas, germany, schengen

Can someone who enters Germany on a Schengen visa go to the Frankfurt Consulate and apply for a US visit visa? Or can only residents of Germany or Frankfurt apply from there?

Would the waiting time be the same for everyone in this case?

Comment: The US State Department website has a page to look up visa wait times for each consulate.  [Visa Appointment Wait Times](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html)